# Where's the copy-paste progress window?

Tags: nautilus

Assume, I want to copy a file from my home folder to a removable drive.  I right click the file and click send to... then I get the option to send to removable drive... then I click send and the dialogue closes! Where is the copy progress dialogue?

Comment: that must be the longest headline I've ever seen! LOL

Comment: @Alvar lol. couldnt make it shorter! btw doesnt this happen to you ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amith, this thing just happened with me too. I found my solution by myself, is just tip <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and select the "File Operation" that you will get the copy-past progress window

I know that could be late to answer this, but I think that this answer can helps people with the same problem.

Edgar.

Answer (score 2):

This dialogue only appears when you are sending files that will actually take a while to copy. You didn't say the size or number of files, but I'm going to guess it was something small.

In such a case, don't be alarmed, it's normal not to see anything.

Comment: the dialogue doesnt appear at all! It didnt appear in maverick nor does it appears in natty! even with a huge movie file (1gb) it does appear when i send to bluetooth device not when i send to removable drive!

Comment: @amithviswanath: Then you need to report a bug :P (cause that is an abnormal behaviour)

Comment: I didnt realise that I was the only one with the problem! will file a bug report soon!